# ( Socket.io ) One socket connection multiple rooms

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io

I'm having problems with socket.io.
I try to create a single socket connection where this is connected to multiple rooms.

This is my current code:

```
function JoinRoom(id){
   socket = io(domain);

   socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        console.log('Connected to ' + room);
        socket.emit('room', room);
   });

   socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
   });
}
```

The problem is that if I remove the var **socket.io(domain)** function was not connected and do not receive data from the room.

Example:

```
socket = io(domain);
function JoinRoom(id){

   socket.on('connect', function (data) {
        console.log('Connected to ' + room);
        socket.emit('room', room);
   });

   socket.on('message', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
   });
}
```

If I take the socket.io() function of the JoinRoom() function I do not receive messages message or anything. It does not work.
What am I doing wrong? Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

On the client, create an event to indicate the access room.

On the server, apply the access logic.

## Client

```
var socket = io('http://localhost');

function JoinRoom(data){
    socket.emit("join", data);
}

var data = {
    room:'ejemplo'
};

JoinRoom(data);
```

## Server

```
var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('join', function(data){
        console.log(data); // data = { room: String, ...}
        socket.join(data.room);  
    });

socket.on('leave', function(data){
    socket.leave(data.room); 
});
```